# Angular ng build --aot giving template parse errors

Tags: angular

Getting Errors while building angular 4 based project with following options,

ng build --aot or following the documentation over here (https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

Errors are like,

1. Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
2. Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
3. Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.

Is there any work-around or solution to it?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing `Browser Module`, check if you have imported it.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
  ...
})
```

Same thing could be for `routerLink`, missing `RouterModule`

The `BrowserModule` should be imported in the `app.module`, in all other modules you should import `CommonModule` instead.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq): if you are writing a browser application, you should import the `BrowserModule` from `@angular/platform-browser` rather than  `CommonModule`. But other than that you're right, that is what's missing.

Comment: Not helping. still getting the same thing.

Comment: Can you share some code? How does component you are trying to use look like?

Comment: i have a file common-modules.ts in which i have all the common modules put as const array to be used in other modules.  like, export const commonModules = [RouteModule, BrowserModule, ...] and in my module I am using like @NgModule({ import: commonModules.contact([EntityModule])})